# How to disable error reporting in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

I keep getting a flashing red icon in the bottom right-hand corner of Android Studio every time it wants me to report a bug in the IDE. It's really irritating! Does anyone know how to disable this feature please? I'm using Studio 2.3.3.

Comment: Does it go away when you report the bug(s)?

Comment: It does - but then reappears when the same bug happens again, which occurs regularly. And the icon still reappears even if you've reported it once, twice, ....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just report the bug... It helps the team behind Android Studio to improve their product. Wouldn't you want people to do the same when your own app crashes ?

If you still want to hide it, the only solution is to remove the entire status bar in `View > Status Bar`

Comment: I have reported it - multiple times. But that doesn't stop Studio wanting me to report it again. They should at least offer the opportunity to suppress reporting of a previously reported bug (I think Eclipse does this). Or, even better, suppress bug reporting altogether. They ask you if you want to report bugs when you install Studio but they don't seem to let you turn it off later if you change your mind for whatever reason.

Comment: Thanks. If that works when a bug appears again I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: let me know how it went

Comment: Thanks! Hiding the status bar means I don't see the annoying flashing red exclamation mark any more. Ideally we could keep the status bar and simply disable the error reporting (or make it automatic). You still see a red icon on the Event Log tab but that's easier to ignore as it doesn't flash.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, it's important to have feedback, but it's exhausting to have to see a flashing red icon/make reports every 5 minutes. There are much better ways to implement that feature.

Comment: I will be happy to report any error they want. Just add an option to make it automatic after user's consent.

Answer (score 0):

If you use kotlin, this gradle setting will disable that behaviour:

```
android {
    kotlinOptions {
        allWarningsAserrors = false
    }
}
```

No ideea how to disable it by default, for me this only happens on only one device